# Render layout without a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

I'm writing a Rails 3.2 app with backbone, and since I only need rails to render one page, I have no need for a controller to back the index page.

Is there a way to render the layout (application.html.erb) without a controller? I imagine it would be a configuration in the routes.rb file?

My first thought was to move it to index.html in the /public directory, but I need to take advantage of erb for javascript includes and CSRF helpers, etc.

Comment: What's wrong with having a controller with one method? How much time will bypassing the Rails router save you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get that you don't need the controller to do anything, but Rails is "opinionated" software; it expects a controller and a view, because that is the way it was designed, and trying to work around that is going to give you a lot of trouble.

Just

1. create an empty controller class in `/app/controllers/main_controller.rb`
2. create an empty view file `/app/views/main/index.html.erb`
3. set up a route like `:root => 'main#index'`

Easy peasy.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I have no, I was just hoping there was a lighter weight solution.